# JSX (Photoshop) - document resolution in dpi

Tags: photoshop, jsx

I'm working with a jsx script in Photoshop that resizes images to a specific size. The resolution is set at 200 dpi. After running the script, I can check this under Image > Image Size.

Problem is, depending on the image, it initially tends to show the resolution in dots/cm instead of dots/inch. The number itself is correct either way, but I'd like to see it mentioned there as the latter. Is there a way to realize this in JSX?

Thanks!

J

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to open your Info Panel by going to Window > Info, and then click on the x/y coordinates dropdown in the Info Panel and select inches. The dropdown is the + toward the lower-left of the panel, with the little down arrow at the bottom right of the + symbol (The plus is actually an x axis and y axis representing a coordinate plane). After that, when you check under Image > Image Size, it should show you all information in inches instead of centimeters. This should also show you inches anywhere else you look in Photoshop's interface, too, such as the rulers.

[image: Info Panel]

An exception would be that when using selection tools, such as the marquee tool with a setting like "fixed size" selected, you can override the units setting by typing in another unit in the Width and Height sections at the top of the window. You can even mix and match units, making a precise selection that is, for example, exactly 250 pixels (px in the Width setting) by 30 points (pt in the Height setting). And when you check your image size, it should still show you results in inches.

[image: Marquee tool settings]

And finally, to answer your question as it was asked, the following code will change your rulerUnits preference without opening the Info Panel.

```
#target Photoshop
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.INCHES;
```

Note that if you want to write other scripts, you can change the rulerUnits to whatever units the script calls for, and then at the end of the script put your units back the way you had them.

```
#target Photoshop

// Save the original rulerUnits setting to a variable
var originalRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;

// Change the rulerUnits to Inches
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.INCHES;

//
// Do magical scripty stuff here...
//

// Restore the original setting
preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;

// List of rulerUnits settings available
// Units.CM
// Units.INCHES
// Units.MM
// Units.PERCENT
// Units.PICAS
// Units.PIXELS
// Units.POINTS
```